# Peano axioms and Herbrand's theorem

Tags: logic, peano-axioms

We denote the Peano axioms with $\mathsf {PA}$ and $S=\{0,1,+,\cdot,<\}$ denotes the language of number theory.

Let $\varphi$ be the formula $$(1+1)\cdot v_2\equiv(v_0+v_1)\cdot(v_0+v_1+1)+(1+1)\cdot v_0$$
I have to prove that $$\mathsf {PA}\vdash\forall x\forall y\exists z[\varphi(x,y,z)\wedge\forall u(\varphi(x,y,z)\longrightarrow u\equiv z)]$$
Now I thought about using Herbrand's theorem by proving that the negation of $\varphi$, which is equivalent to
$$\forall x\forall y\forall z\exists u\hspace{3pt}\psi$$
where $$\psi=\neg(\varphi(x,y,z)\wedge\varphi(x,y,u)\longrightarrow u\equiv z)$$
is inconsistent.
(so if i can get rid of that $\exists$ quantifier, i could do the following)

For this I have to find variable free terms $t_i^j\in T^S$ such that
$$\bigwedge_{j=0}^N \psi\frac{t_0^j,t_1^j,t_2^j,t_3^j}{x,y,z,u}$$
is inconsistent.
But i do not know how to find these terms.
any help would be very much appreciated.

edit: i just realized that the $\forall u$ becomes $\exists u$ in the negation, which would be bad because i would have to get rid of the $\exists$ in order to use Herbrand.
and if i want to get rid of that $\exists$, i would get an extra negation in the front, which would not work with Herbrand (i think)

Comment: I imagine that $\equiv$ must be $=$...

Comment: well in the language of first order logic we were using the $\equiv$ symbol, but yes it is basically the same i guess

Comment: Basically, you have to prove that : $∀x∀y∃!zφ(x,y,z)$ where $φ(x,y,z)$ says that $(x+y)⋅(x+y+1)+(1+1)⋅x$ is *even*.

Comment: i see, i think i got on the right track now. i was not entirely sure why i can use the fact that $1\cdot x=x$, but it is just simple induction.

Comment: If so, we have to prove that : $(x+y)⋅(x+y+1)$ is *even*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so first of all much thanks to Mauro ALLEGRANZA.
for anyone who may stumble across this, here is my attempted solution (it might be a little messy, but i hope it is all correct):
First note that by induction we get $\forall x\hspace{5pt} 1\cdot x=x$, since $0\cdot 1=0$ and $1\cdot(x+1)=1\cdot x+1$.
Secondly, we show that $\forall y\exists z[(1+1)\cdot z=y\cdot(y+1)]$ by induction over $y$. Clearly $(1+1)\cdot 0=0\cdot(0+1)$
    Furthermore $(y+1)\cdot(y+1+1)=(y+1)\cdot(y+1)+y+1=y\cdot(y+1)+y+1+y+1=y\cdot(y+1)+(1+1)\cdot(y+1)=(1+1)\cdot(z+y+1)$.
    Now we use induction over $x$ to show $\forall x\forall y\exists z[(1+1)\cdot z=(x+y)\cdot(x+y+1)]$.
    The case $x=0$ follows from our previous result. Furthermore
    \begin{align*}
  (x+1+y)\cdot(x+1+y+1)&=(x+y+1)\cdot(x+y+1)+x+y+1 \\
                       &=\underbrace{(x+y)\cdot(x+y+1)}_{=(1+1)\cdot z}+(1+1)\cdot(x+y+1) \\
                       &=(1+1)\cdot(x+y+z+1)
\end{align*}
    Then we have $\forall x\forall y\exists z[(1+1)\cdot z+(1+1)\cdot x\overset{2.}{=}(x+y)\cdot(x+y+1)+(1+1)\cdot x]$.
    Therefore, by putting $z=z+x$ and with part 2, we get 
$$\forall x\forall y\exists z[(1+1)\cdot z\overset{2.}{=}(x+y)\cdot(x+y+1)+(1+1)\cdot x]$$
    It remains to show uniqueness. Use induction over $u$. We have
$\varphi(x,y,z)\wedge\varphi(x,y,0)\longrightarrow 0=(x+y)\cdot(x+y+1)+(1+1)\cdot x\longrightarrow x=0\wedge y=0\longrightarrow z=0\longrightarrow u=z$
    The induction step yields
    \begin{align*}
  \varphi(x,y,u+1)&\longrightarrow(1+1)\cdot(u+1)=(x+y)\cdot(x+y+1)+(1+1)\cdot x \\
                  &\longrightarrow(1+1)\cdot u+1+1=(x+y)\cdot(x+y+1)+(1+1)\cdot x \\
                  &\overset{\text{induction step}}{\longrightarrow}(1+1)\cdot z+1+1=(x+y)\cdot(x+y+1)+(1+1)\cdot x \\
                  &\longrightarrow z+1=u+1
\end{align*}
    This yields our desired result.